# Replace MOSFET AO4433 With FDS6679

Tags: mosfet, laptop

Good day guys. This is my first time posting, hope you can help me a bit with this.

My Sony Vaio laptop from 2009 has two damaged AO4433 MOSFETS near the power supply connector. I want to replace them, but I can't find this exact model in my city. I have an old laptop motherboard (for spare parts) that has some FDS6679 MOSFETS that I can use.

Can I replace the damaged AO4433 with the FDS6679?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Bring up the datasheets for each of them and do a comparison.

Comment: They look similar. The bigger issue is what caused the damaged MOSFETs in the first place. Typically a blown component is not the culprit, but the weakest link in a larger failure.

Comment: What distributors do you have access to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FDS6679 has 1/2 the RdsOn at the same Vgs (-10) so it will run cooler yet have more gate capacitance, which may slow down the gate driver and increase VI SOA dissipation.

Not much to lose in trying, but try a low current limited lab supply source to bypass the FETs to investigate root cause.

Gate charge * RdsOn =T product tends to constant but as a FoM varies with other tradeoffs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Tony. I acknowledge that I am a bit lost with this, because I'm not an EE, nor a technician. I am more of a electronics hobbyst, but I still have a lot to learn. I will try swapping the AO4433 with the FDS6679 (It's an old laptop anyways, so, as you say, there's little to lose). I will comment if it works.

Comment: Be static aware and safe in handling touch case before pins.  This is a dual complementary and similar http://products.niko-sem.com/images/product/1358404287970837516.pdf beware of fake cheap parts on web.

Comment: Well, It works now, I have been testing a few hours with Memtest86 and seems to be working OK, without crashing, overheating, or shutting down. I wanted to upload a photo of the board, but I don't know how to link an image here.

Comment: it's a frequent issue , with work-arounds if you search   Memtest is great if you pass the higher Test numbers for cross-talk patterns.  Disable you useless startups to keep it cool.

Answer (score 1):

They don't look all that similar to me, the proposed replacement has more than 2.5x the gate charge. Look for something with similar gate charge as well as voltage, current, Vgs(th) and Rds(on) ratings.

Those parts are obsolete but you may still be able to scare some up. Beware of dubious sources though (Ali, eBay etc.)

Answer (score 0):

> two damaged AO4433 MOSFETS near the power supply connector

When you **choose** a component for a design, you should consider: -

- The desired circuit functionality and
- The desired circuit performance and
- The data sheets of candidate components

When you **replace** that component with another, you should consider: -

- The desired circuit functionality and
- The desired circuit performance and
- The data sheets of candidate component

So, with no visible circuit to study, it means no clear understanding of: -

- The desired circuit functionality and
- The desired circuit performance

And no clear idea of what component can be chosen

Comment: Sadly, there are no schematics for this Sony Motherboard.